# YARD - how to document @!method YARD on class level rather than instance level?

Tags: ruby, yard

By default, such methods are created on the instance level from what I see.
How to document class/static level methods instead?

I checked https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#method but it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be adjusted via [`@!scope`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Tags/ScopeDirective) which can be either `class` or `instance`:

```
class Foo
  # @!scope class
  #
  # @!method bar
  #   @return [Bar] enum scope
  # @!method baz
  #   @return [Baz] enum scope
end
```

See [Documenting Custom DSL Methods](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#documenting-custom-dsl-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround using blank eigen-class seems to work fine but perhaps someone knows a more idiomatic and clean way of doing it?

```ruby
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    # @!method bar
    #   @return [Bar] enum scope
    # @!method baz
    #   @return [Baz] enum scope
  end
  enum status: FooStatuses
end
```